# System.DateTime and SQL Server DateTime2 Comparison Yielding Unexpected Result

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have included a complete reproduction below but here is the basic operation that is causing strange results.

1. INSERT a row into a SQL Server table with a `datetime2(7)` column and set the column to `SYSUTCDATETIME()`
2. Read the datetime of that record into a .net `System.DateTime` type (using `System.Data.SqlClient`)
3. Run a query that is `SELECT * FROM table WHERE DateColumn < @readDate`
4. About 50% of the time, that query will return the created record, even though the code is passing in the date it read from the created column

My assumption is this is a precision issue (e.g., .net `datetime` higher precision than SQL Server `datetime2(7)` or vice versa).

My questions, then, are:

- Why does this issue occur?
- How can the code be written so these queries would consistently work correctly

I have also discovered the following:

- Using `GETUTCDATE()` instead of `SYSUTCDATETIME()` only causes failures 20% of the time
- The issue does not occur using the `datetime` or `datetime2([1-2])` date types, it is only when using precision of 3 or higher with datetime2 the issue occurs

```cs
using System;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace DateTimeTesting
{
  public class Program
  {
    public static void Main()
    {
      const string connectionString = "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Trusted_Connection=True;ConnectRetryCount=0";
      const int numRuns = 1000;
      const int printLimiter = 100;

      var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
      connection.Open();

      using (var dropDbCommand = connection.CreateCommand())
      {
        dropDbCommand.CommandText = @"IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.databases WHERE name = N'DateTimeTesting') BEGIN CREATE DATABASE [DateTimeTesting] END;";
        dropDbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
      }

      connection.ChangeDatabase("DateTimeTesting");

      using (var createTableCommand = connection.CreateCommand())
      {
        createTableCommand.CommandText = "IF OBJECT_ID('JustChecking') IS NULL CREATE TABLE JustChecking (id INT IDENTITY(1,1), CreateDateUTC datetime2(7))";
        createTableCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
      }

      try
      {
        int weirdCounter = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < numRuns; ++i)
        {
          if ((i + 1) % printLimiter == 0)
          {
            Console.WriteLine($"Run #{i + 1}");
          }

          int id = -1;
          DateTime found = DateTime.MinValue;

          using (var insertCommand = connection.CreateCommand())
          {
            insertCommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO JustChecking (CreateDateUTC) VALUES (SYSUTCDATETIME()); SELECT @@IDENTITY as id;";
            using var insertReader = insertCommand.ExecuteReader();
            if (insertReader.Read())
            {
              id = (int)insertReader.GetDecimal(0);
            }
          }

          using (var selectCommand = connection.CreateCommand())
          {
            selectCommand.CommandText = "SELECT CreateDateUTC FROM JustChecking WHERE id = @id";
            selectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);

            using var selectReader = selectCommand.ExecuteReader();

            if (selectReader.Read())
            {
              found = selectReader.GetDateTime(0);
            }
          }

          using (var weirdCommand = connection.CreateCommand())
          {
            weirdCommand.CommandText = "SELECT id, CreateDateUTC FROM JustChecking WHERE CreateDateUtc < @inputDate AND id = @inputId";
            weirdCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@inputDate", found);
            weirdCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@inputId", id);

            using var weirdReader = weirdCommand.ExecuteReader();
            while (weirdReader.Read())
            {
              weirdCounter++;

              if (weirdCounter % printLimiter == 0)
              {
                Console.WriteLine($"Weird #{weirdCounter} = id: {weirdReader.GetInt32(0)}, createDateUtc: {weirdReader.GetDateTime(1):O}, inputDate: {found:O}");
              }
            }
          }
        }

        Console.WriteLine($"Out of {numRuns} runs found {weirdCounter} weird results which accounted for {(double)weirdCounter / (double)numRuns} percent of runs");

        connection.ChangeDatabase("master");
        using (var dropDbCommand = connection.CreateCommand())
        {
          dropDbCommand.CommandText = "DROP DATABASE DateTimeTesting";
          dropDbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
      }
      finally
      {
        connection.Close();
        connection.Dispose();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Versions used:

- .NET Core 3.1 (SDK v3.1.301)
- `System.Data.SqlClient` v4.8.1
- LocalDB version = 13.1.4001.0

Comment: A better question would be "why are you doing this"? If you want to find changes since a specific database version you can use change tracking. A `datetime2`, no matter the precision, will always be lossy.

Comment: In any case,  `System.DateTime`. System.DateTime stores dates as [a tick count](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.ticks?view=netcore-3.1), which still has a precision of 10μs. That's  *less* than datetime(2)'s precision of 100ns.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos specifically, I am just deleting records older than a certain record. I found that using `DELETE FROM table WHERE CreateTime < @recordTime` from the DB was sometimes deleting more than I had expected it do. It's not actually a big deal that it was deleting one extra record, but it got me curious, and made me wonder whether i was making some bigger mistake.

Comment: table partitioning would be a better choice then. It's transparent, available in all editions and deleting old data means simply removing the oldest partition in a table, an almost instantaneous operation

Comment: @madreflection that does seem to fix it. Now I need to see if I was actually reproducing the problem correctly. I was technically seeing it when using entity framework, but went with the raw sql client to see if it was reproducible more directly.

Comment: Partitioning allows you to move older partitions to slower storage before removing them too

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thank you for the advice, I can took into table partitioning as a solution to my specific problem.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, according to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime), `System.DateTime` uses *"100-nanosecond units called ticks"*.

Comment: @madreflection (facepalm) I read the same page incorrectly.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: Hey, my user avatar came in handy. ;)

Comment: Yes. I think the *real* solution would be to use partitioning. The answer to the specific question though is what you noticed

Comment: @madreflection somehow your comment got deleted but wanted to repost the article you linked that I found helpful https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/

Comment: @BillKeller: I deleted it because its correctness was called into question and somewhere along the way I stopped trusting my gut when it comes to what I know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a breaking change introduced in SQL Server 2016 that changed how DATETIME values are converted to DATETIME2 values, and because of this it's critical to always use DATETIME2 parameters when comparing to DATETIME2 columns.

> Under database compatibility level 130, implicit conversions from
> datetime to datetime2 data types show improved accuracy by accounting
> for the fractional milliseconds, resulting in different converted
> values. Use explicit casting to datetime2 datatype whenever a mixed
> comparison scenario between datetime and datetime2 datatypes exists.
> For more information, see this [Microsoft Support Article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4010261/sql-server-and-azure-sql-database-improvements-in-handling-data-types).

[Breaking changes to Database Engine features in SQL Server 2016](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/breaking-changes-to-database-engine-features-in-sql-server-2016?view=sql-server-2017)

see also this [blog](http://www.dbdelta.com/sql-server-2016-and-azure-sql-database-v12-breaking-change/)

Essentially this is *yet another* reason to never use AddWithValue, as that sets the parameter type based on the .NET parameter value type, when it should always be set based on the SQL Server column type instead.

To fix just use a DATETIME2 parameter.

```
weirdCommand.Parameters.Add("@inputDate",System.Data.SqlDbType.DateTime2, 7).Value = found;
```

Comment: Thank you david!

Answer (score 1):

Using a DateTime like this is rather unusual and suggest the real problem is something else. From the comments it appears the *actual* problem is how to delete older records.

The most effective way to do that is to use [table partitioning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/partitions/partitioned-tables-and-indexes?view=sql-server-ver15). It's transparent to applications, available in all editions (Express to Enterprise) since SQL Server 2016.

Deletion can be almost instantaneous - you can use [partition switching between a full table and an empty one](https://sqlsunday.com/2014/08/24/reloading-fact-tables-with-zero-downtime/), effectively making the empty partition part of the source table. This is just a metadata operation, making it very fast. You could also move partitions from the live table to an archive table, possibly stored in slower media